# For Loop Pascal Script

Tags: loops, pascal

I'm trying to cut down the code, but I can't seem to do it. I have 35 "TfrxEdiTControl" (Tedit?) so I want to cut it down. The downside is I'm not sure what the language is, but I do think is Pascal Script.

Right now I have this:

```
if EPRD1.text <> '' then
  begin
      Tab.SQL.Add(','+EPRD1.text);
      TabD.SQL.Add(','+EPRD1.text);              
  end;         
  if EPRD2.text <> '' then
      begin
          Tab.SQL.Add(','+EPRD2.text);
          TabD.SQL.Add(','+EPRD2.text);              
      end;
```

Till EPRD35, so I want to do it in a For loop.

I try the following:

```
  for i := 1 to (35) do
  begin
      erpdConcat := FindComponent('EPRD'+IntToStr(i));
      if erpdConcat is TEdit then
          begin
               if TEdit(erpdConcat).text <> '' then
                   begin
                       Tab.SQL.Add(','+TEdit(erpdConcat).text);
                       TabD.SQL.Add(','+TEdit(erpdConcat).text);              
                   end;                                                                            
          end;                                                  
  end;
```

But I got a message saying "*Identifier not declared "findcomponent"*"

Comment: Maybe you should ask the one who gave you the code what language it is? Then you could use that to help you search for a function similar to the one you want. Actually knowing what language you're programming in is a good start, or else you won't really be able to do anything useful.

Comment: Maybe also the IDE, the file extension or anything else gives you a hint which language you are using? ;)

Comment: The thing is, they don't know either. They just asked if I could help and gave me the custom editor they have.

Comment: Even if your code did compile, it still contains two possible errors.  1.  Unless the value list you are building already contains at least one element, the Sql.Add statements should not add a comma before the TEdit().Text value.  2.  You do not allow for the fact that the contents to the TEdit(s) may contain a quote character inputted by the user - if it does the Sql will contain a syntax error, unless you use a function like Delphi's QuotedStr()..

Comment: Btw, if you could add to your q the text which precedes `if EPRD1.text <> '' then` in the source, a reader might recognise which implementation of Pascal Script or whatever it is.

Comment: Before the if I have this: Tab.Sql.Add('and p.codigo in(''999999'''); As for the second error you mention. The software they are using don't allow quotes characters when they are introducing texts.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like pascal to me.

FindComponent is a method of TComponent.

I believe the TComponent is in the "classes" unit in both Delphi and Lazarus. So classes must be, of course, in the "uses" clause.

Since FindComponent is a method of a class, it is not a a standalone function, it must be called from a Component.

So if your "TEdit"'s are on, say, a panel called Panel1 then you need to call it as Panel1.FindComponent( etc. ).

HTH